# Copy from one destination to another from Excel macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem whereby this macro will copy a document from one source to another for ONE destination cell. But when I want to select a range of cells it does not work. What principle am I missing that I get an error when I have more than one destination? You will see below my "to path" is a range that gives an error...

```
Sub xArray()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim ToPath As String
    Dim Drive(1 To 2) As String
    Drive(1) = "O"
    Drive(2) = "P"

    For i = 1 To 2
        FromPath = "C:\Users\155555\Desktop\Source"
        ToPath = Range("A1:A2")

        If Right(FromPath, 1) = "\" Then
            FromPath = Left(FromPath, Len(FromPath) - 1)
        End If

        If Right(ToPath, 1) = "\" Then
            ToPath = Left(ToPath, Len(ToPath) - 1)
        End If

        Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

        If fso.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
            MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"

            Exit Sub
        End If

        fso.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath

    Next i

End Sub
```

Thanks,

Comment: What is the purpose of variables `i` and `Drive` in your code? I don't see any usage of them.

Comment: With just A1 there it works perfectly

Comment: @bitoubi , I probably should add that Im no VBA expert at all. How do I adjust this to read A1 and all cells below it until they are blank?

Answer (score 0):

'Destination' has to be a string.
If you want to loop with 'i', you can try:

```
ToPath = Range("A" & i)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub Copy_Files()

    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Range("E1", Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

        FileCopy Source:=cell.Value, Destination:=cell.Offset(, 1).Value

    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: How does this answer your question?

Comment: It does the same thing. And it is working perfectly. In case anyone ever stumbles across this post. Thats what we ended up using. @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå